# gdal java API returning different WKT from gdalinfo

Tags: gdal, gdalinfo

I am running into an interesting bug where the wkt returned from dataset.getProjection() does not match the wkt returned from gdalinfo.

(simplified) code:

```
final Dataset dataset = gdal.open("<somefile>.tif")
...
String wkt = dataset.getProjection()
```

returns:

```
LOCAL_CS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["unretrievable - using WGS84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"],UNIT["metre",1]]
```

whereas running gdalinfo on the SAME file returns:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: testRaster.tif
Size is 718, 720
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Origin = (-15042794.839973239228129,8590031.386050270870328)
Pixel Size = (0.512485836989726,-0.512485836989726)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  COLORSPACE=RGB
  COMPRESSION_RATE_TARGET=4
  VERSION=2
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-15042794.840, 8590031.386) (135d 7'54.21"W, 60d50'37.46"N)
Lower Left  (-15042794.840, 8589662.396) (135d 7'54.21"W, 60d50'31.65"N)
Upper Right (-15042426.875, 8590031.386) (135d 7'42.31"W, 60d50'37.46"N)
Lower Right (-15042426.875, 8589662.396) (135d 7'42.31"W, 60d50'31.65"N)
Center      (-15042610.858, 8589846.891) (135d 7'48.26"W, 60d50'34.56"N)
Band 1 Block=718x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  NoData Value=0
Band 2 Block=718x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  NoData Value=0
Band 3 Block=718x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  NoData Value=0
Band 4 Block=718x2 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
  NoData Value=0
```

My question is: Why am i getting the "LOCAL_CS" value from the java api vs the PROJCS value from gdalinfo?

Comment: Matt, is GDAL_DATA properly set in your Java environment?

Comment: Yes, in both instances '/usr/local/share/gdal' . i even went and hardcoded the value into the run configuration (thinking intelliJ may have been having issues) but no such luck.

Comment: Could you make a small sample image which could be used for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Internet People in the Future:

an ubuntu upgrade had interfered with the source-built gdal install. i am unsure what exactly was being referenced wrong, but removing the repo gdal package and rebuilding gdal seems to have removed the error.